# Set the map to Philippines

Tags: openlayers

How can I set the map to the Philippines?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="ol.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script src="ol/Map" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="ol/View" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="ol/Overlay" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="ol/geom/Point" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="ol/Feature" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="ol/source/Vector" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="ol/layer/Tile" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="ol/source/OSM" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <title>OpenLayer Philippines</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script>
          var attribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
              collapsible: false
          });

          var map = new ol.Map({
              controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }).extend([attribution]),
              layers: [
                  new ol.layer.Tile({
                      source: new ol.source.OSM({
                          url: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.be/osmbe/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                          attributions: [ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION, 'Tiles courtesy of <a href="https://geo6.be/">GEO-608</a>'],
                          maxZoom: 18
                      })
                  })
              ],
              target: 'map',
              view: new ol.View({
                  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([14.59375,121.021569]),
                  maxZoom: 18,
                  zoom: 12
              })
          });

          var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                  features: [
                      new ol.Feature({
                          geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([14.59375,121.021569]))
                      })
                  ]
              })
          });
          map.addLayer(layer);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please mention more details regarding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers uses "LonLat", but these numbers look like Lat-Long of the Philippines:

```
 fromLonLat([14.59375,121.021569]))
```

so try the other way round. There's two places in your code you've done this.